# The subgroups–subalgebras theorem

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is a well known so-called First Fundamnetal Lie theorem that if $G$ is a connected real/complex Lie group then there is the one-to-one correspondence between connected virtual Lie subgroups of $G$ and Lie subalgebras of the corresponding Lie algebra. But it is not an easy task to find a proof of this theorem for complex Lie group.
Are there any references or hints why it is obvious modulo theorem for real Lie groups?

Comment: It is an abstract subgroup with a structure of immersed submanifold (automatically Lie group).

Comment: Complex Lie groups/algebras are real Lie groups/algebras so a proof for real ones works for both unless I am missing something

Comment: Right, the question is whether constructed subgroup is a complex submanifold. Ordinary Frobenius theorem allows to construct only real smooth variety.

Comment: But for a connected Lie group to be complex it is enough that its Lie algebra has a complex structure that is complex linear with respect to the bracket. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338023/almost-complex-structures-on-real-lie-groups).

Comment: Thank you for reference. It is good way to proof what I want but it seems so that anyway I should use Newlander-Nirenberg theorem which is already not very simple. I mean I have induced almost complex structure on subgroup and I have to show that it is integrable.

Comment: Moreover, it is directly a consequence of Newlander-Nirenberg theorem without additional investigations.